# How to create the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+HH:MM in a laravel migration?

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing a project using Laravel 7 and the web services.
My web services will receive datetime data having the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+HH:MM //2020-04-16T12:46:33+02:00
```

I used the following code to create the correct data structure in the migration file but I am pretty sure it won't work correctly:

```
$table->dateTime('creation_date');
```

Can help?

Comment: It's not a Laravel structure, but a database structure. For [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) and MariaDB, date time fields are formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss `, or with fractional, `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.fraction]`. If you want to display it in that format, you'll have to format it after you retrieve it from the database. It won't be done in a migration file.

Comment: Is date('Y-m-d h:i s', strtotime($yourDate)) not helping?

Comment: @sauhardnc That's completely not the point of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You should save the date in standard MySQL format and use Accessor and Mutator to store and retrieve the date from your specific format, you can check the doc here (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i';
```

You can see the full list of formats here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php